# How to remove element for especifict elemendata in Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

First I have Class Watcher with method loadInMovie that load the elements  for each genre.

```
    /*Load elements for each Genre*/
    Watcher.loadInMovie(genre.NON_FICTION, 10);
    Watcher.loadInMovie(genre.GENERAL_FICTION, 10);
    Watcher.loadInMovie(genre.SCIENCE_FICTION, 10);
    Watcher.loadInMovie(genre.WESTERN, 10);
```

In the method I load the information with the Movie structure Object

```
    @Override
    public void loadInMovie(Genre genre,int cantidad)  
    {
        for (int x=0;x<cantidad;x++)
        {
            al.add(new Movie(x,genre,"Movie" + x,"",1));
        }
    }
```

after that, I have another method that remove the elements from the previous method.

```
@Override
public Movie RemoveMovie (Genre genre) 
{
    /*Movie*/
    /*array clone*/
    ArrayList<Movie> alClone = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    alClone=(ArrayList)al.clone();

    /*remove Movie*/

    al.remove(al.size()-1);
    return alClone.get(alClone.size()-1);
}
```

I want to remove the element for especific elementdata inside the array list. For example the arrayList contains Object Movie with Genre ScienFiction I want remove the last element for this genre. Remove id 9 because are 10 element starting of 0. but with this code remove the element id 39. How Can I filter for genre and remove the last element?.

Comment: If `removeMovie` should return a `Movie` object, how are you returning an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Remember that the Arraylist has the element Movie " ArrayList<Movie> alClone = new ArrayList<Movie>();" with this remove the Book39 but i want to remove the Book9 in genre ScienceFiction for example.

Comment: Misread, disregard. So, this method return the Movie it removed, right?

Comment: Yes, for that I make a arrayClone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate in a reverse way:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ListIterator;


    public class MovieListExample {

        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

        public class Movie {

            int id;
            Genre genre;

            public Movie(int id, Genre genre)
            {
                this.id = id;
                this.genre = genre;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return "Movie{" + "id=" + id + ", genre=" + genre + '}';
            }

        }

        public enum Genre {

            NON_FICTION,
            GENERAL_FICTION,
            SCIENCE_FICTION,
            WESTERN
        }

        public void loadInMovie(Genre genre, int amount)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < amount; x++) {
                movies.add(new Movie(x, genre));
            }
        }

        public Movie removeLastMovieWithGenre(Genre genre)
        {
            ListIterator<Movie> iterator = movies.listIterator(movies.size());
            while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
                Movie movie = iterator.previous();
                if (genre.equals(movie.genre)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    return movie;
                }
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("No movie found"); // or return null, or change return type to boolean or void.
        }



        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            MovieListExample movieListExample = new MovieListExample();
            movieListExample.loadInMovie(Genre.NON_FICTION, 3);
            movieListExample.loadInMovie(Genre.GENERAL_FICTION, 3);
            movieListExample.loadInMovie(Genre.SCIENCE_FICTION, 3);
            movieListExample.loadInMovie(Genre.WESTERN, 3);

            System.out.println("SciFi movies in collection");
            movieListExample.movies.stream().filter(movie -> movie.genre.equals(Genre.SCIENCE_FICTION)).forEach(movie -> System.out.println(movie));

            Movie removeLastMovieWithGenre = movieListExample.removeLastMovieWithGenre(Genre.SCIENCE_FICTION);
            System.out.println("Removed " + removeLastMovieWithGenre);
            System.out.println("Remains in collection");
            movieListExample.movies.stream().filter(movie -> movie.genre.equals(Genre.SCIENCE_FICTION)).forEach(movie -> System.out.println(movie));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot create the object movie with iterator.previous()